# Default value in select still there after submit

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a problem while creating a  with a default value contained in my current object.

The value is correctly set in the field, but when I submit the form, the default value is still there, even if the user chose another value in the list...

Here is my controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String createForm(final ModelMap modelMap){

    User user;

    user = new User();

    user.setGroup("HelpDesk");
    user.setName("John");


    ArrayList<String> groupList = new ArrayList<>();

    groupList.add("Admin");
    groupList.add("HelpDesk");
    groupList.add("GroupManager");
    groupList.add("Others");


    modelMap.addAttribute("user", user);
    modelMap.addAttribute("groupList", groupList);

    return "/user/user-add"; 
}

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("user") final User user, BindingResult result) {

    userValidator.validate(user, result, groupList);

    logger.info(user.getGroup()); //Will print "HelpDesk,Admin" for instance

    return "...";

}
```

And here is my JSP :

```
<table>
    <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user">

        <tr>
                <td>Name:</td>
                <td><form:input path="name"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="name" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td>Group:</td>
                <td><form:select path="group" items="${groupList}" multiple="single"/></td>
                <td><form:errors path="group" cssClass="error" /></td>
            </tr>


            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
            </tr>

        </form:form>
    </table>
```

For instance, if i choose "Admin" in the select list, i'll get "HelpDesk, Admin" in the property "group" of my user after submitting the form...

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you considered adding a blank field at the beginning of the list? Or would that be an ugly workaround for you? :)

Comment: Using Firebug or chrome developer tools, can you find the value that is getting posted from the browser?

Comment: @GGeorge it's not that ugly, but i would like to understand why it isn't currently working

Comment: @user636334 according to chrome developer tools, the only value sent is the one selected by the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I see your "POST" method or the "onSubmit" method? In your post method you must specify the User object as your model attribute or command.

Comment: Edited in the original question.

Comment: But why is User object declared as 'final'?

Comment: Try removing the final qualifier for User in your post method.

Comment: It was a bad Copy/Paste from a tutorial... And removing the "final" resolves everything ! Thank you :-)